# Launch an external JS engine with forwarding data from the browser

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, v8, deobfuscation, malware-detection

I want to analyze a large and confusing JS code. The code is heavily obfuscated and even tools like [JStillery](https://github.com/mindedsecurity/JStillery) cannot work with it.

I would like to somehow build one of the open JS-interpreters, run it outside the browser and debug in more traditional ways, if necessary, applying patches inside the interpreter.

Unfortunately, the code uses DOM and cannot be executed without a browser.

The question is: are there any known techniques to take any external engine (such as V7, V8, [DukTape](https://duktape.org/), JerryScript, MuJS, quad-wheel, QuickJS, tiny-js, ...) and run code inside them that contains calls to DOM and other browser parts?

Answer (score 0):

There are pure-JavaScript implementations of the DOM, such as https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom. Not sure how useful that is for your use case, but it does address your primary question: it allows you to run JavaScript that assumes a browser environment outside the browser environment.

I believe jsdom is fairly accurate in its implementation; there are other implementations out there that are more mock-like. Either way, there are probably some remaining differences, so heavily obfuscated code may well include mechanisms to detect emulated environments...